# Mongodb Aggregation to get Summary

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to find an aggregation equation using Spring Data Mongodb, and struggling to get it right:

Lets say I have this kind of data in mongodb:

```
{ "_id": 1, "channel": "fb", "store": "store1"},
{ "_id": 2, "channel": "app", "store": "store2"},
{ "_id": 3, "channel": "sms", "store": "store3"},
{ "_id": 4, "channel": "fb", "store": "store4"},
{ "_id": 5, "channel": "app", "store": "store3"},
{ "_id": 6, "channel": "app", "store": "store2"},
{ "_id": 7, "channel": "sms", "store": "store1"},
{ "_id": 8, "channel": "fb", "store": "store4"},
{ "_id": 9, "channel": "app", "store": "store2"},
{ "_id": 10, "channel": "fb", "store": "store2"},
```

Now, what I want out of this is to provide a summary of each store that has total count of each channel in an object that has:

```
class Summary {
  private String store;
  private int fbCount;
  private int smsCount;
  private int appCount;
  private int totalCount;
}
```

If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate. Sounds like it should have a very obvious solution, but my aggregation queries are not working as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have and expected json response ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "store": "$store",
                "channel": "$channel"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This query will return count for each `store` and `channel`.

Or if you want to get counts in one object, please try:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$store",
            fb:  {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$channel', 'fb']}, 1,0]}},
            app: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$channel', 'app']}, 1,0]}},
            sms: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$channel', 'sms']}, 1,0]}},
            total: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

If I can do anything else feel free to ask:).

Comment: I was able to get this to work. However, as you saw, the problem I faced was now I have four objects with same storeId. I was hoping to somehow manage to aggregate to get data that fits in above object I mentioned. Basically, have a [store, totalCount, fbCount, smsCount, appCount] in one instance.

Comment: in this case you can use this query:
`db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$store",
            fb:  {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$channel', 'fb']}, 1,0]}},
            app: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$channel', 'app']}, 1,0]}},
            sms: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$channel', 'sms']}, 1,0]}},
            total: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
])`
you can check edited answer.
Hope this will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

@andranikasl had the good start, but you need to transform your documents to fit your expected output (and your Object). Here's the way :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "store": "$store",
        "channel": "$channel"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.store",
      channels: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.channel",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      channels: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $concatArrays: [
            "$channels",
            [
              {
                k: "totalCount",
                v: {
                  $sum: "$channels.v"
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      store: "$_id",
      fbCount: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$channels.fb",
          0
        ]
      },
      smsCount: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$channels.sms",
          0
        ]
      },
      appCount: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$channels.app",
          0
        ]
      },
      totalCount: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$channels.totalCount",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Go7M8mzMarn)